# What is the default cursor location?

Tags: grails

My book collection is getting really big.  When I get a list like `def bookList = Book.findAllBy...()` for example, is GORM returning a client-side cursor or a server-side cursor?  I am using MariaDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GORM doesn't use cursors at all, or at least not by default.  (I don't *think* they're supported but not 100% sure on that.  Looks like they're barely supported in Hibernate.)

What you'll get is essentially all queried objects in memory.  You can control which fields are lazily loaded though, for references to other objects.
Depending on what you mean by "really big" it may be wise for you do do pagination and offset yourself.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Got it!  I have a single table with lot of rows.  So, if the query returns 10K rows from one table, it will just load all these 10K rows to the memory. So, I will see the browser hang while the controller is loading the records from the database, and the server swapping files to the hard disk.

Comment: Yes, unless your rows are very small or you have a lot of resources, you probably should look into max/offset/sort.  Good luck!